# Android WebView: deny click on div tag

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm now pretty stuck at following problem.
I got this HTML Code (Snippet) which I have no access to:

```
<div class="story_pic"
style="backgroundimage:url('http://#####.jpg');"
data-origpic="http://#####.jpg">
</div>
```

Now I want to disable the click possibility on these pictures on my Android WebView.

What I've tried:
1) OnTouchListener

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();
        Log.i(TAG, "getExtra = " + hr.getExtra() + "\t\t Type=" + hr.getType());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Creates: getExtra = null         Type=0

2.) WebViewClient:

```
private class SampleWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "#url: " + url);
        }
    }
```

Creates: nothing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return true;
    }  
});
```

Using android:clickable="false" does not disable touch events.

---

## **Another way**

Create a custom `WebViewClient` and override  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` & `shouldOverrideKeyEvent`. For example:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shuldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
         // Do something with the event here
         return true;
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
             // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
             return false;
        }

        // reject anything other
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have mentioned that I want to disable specific "div" parts of the Website, not every link :(

Comment: @Override shouldOverrideUrlLoading and shouldOverrideKeyEvent are never called when clicking this link (maybe cause it's handled by css)